# C program, pointer argument won't hold values

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-arrays

Hi guys I'm sorry to bother you with this but I'm starting to loose it here.. 
I have recently started programming in C again and I have run into some kind bug that just I can't figure out..
My C program is(should be) an easy one, so it needs to do the following:
An undefined number of natural elements is read form the keyboard until a 0 is read. After that it has to compute the product of all elements and compute the number of 0-s on the end of that result..

```
int input(int* v)                      {

    int n = 0;   
    do                                                            
    {
        n = n + 1;
        v = (int*) realloc(v,n*sizeof(int));        printf("Enter number %d: ",n);          scanf("%d",&v[n-1]);
    }
    while(v[n-1] != 0);           
    n--;
    return n;  }

int tZeros(int* v, int eNb)     {    
    int i;
    int  val = 1;
    for(i = 0; i < eNb; i++)
    {
        val = val * v[i];        
    }

    i=0;
    while(val % 10 == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }  
    return i; }

int main (int argc, char** argv)     {

    int* v = NULL;                                                  
    int eNb = input(&(*v));                                          
    if(eNb>0)                                                       
    {
        int zeros = tZeros(v, eNb);
        printf("The number of ending zeros in the product of the given numbers is: %d",zeros);

    }
    else
    {
        printf("No elements to do computations with!\n");
    }
    free(v);
    return 0; 
    }
```

The input function should return two things: The number of elements and the actual elements in the dynamic array.. But after the input function runs the values entered there are all lost..
I pass the argument into input as a pointer so it should change the values at the correct addresses right?

All suggestions are welcome!
Thnx!

P.s. I think the problem is with my array v.. after exiting the input function it looses all values..

Comment: What's wrong with SO's markdown parser?

Comment: Dont have time to check it all but.. `i=0;
    while(val % 10 == 0)
    {
        i++;
    }` this will either loop for ever not loop at all.

Comment: @Radek S: What are you referring to?

Comment: @Ed some of the code is not highlighted and has the wrong font. At least on my iPod touch.

Comment: sorry about the code.. it's probably because I just copy-past-ed it..

Comment: Looks ok to me, though I have seen a bug which causes none of the code to be highlighted at all in the past.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everything in C is passed by value, so when you perform the assignment:

```
v = (int*) realloc(v,n*sizeof(int));
```

You are assigning a new value to *the local copy* of the variable `v`.  If you want to change the value of the pointer itself (as opposed to modifying *what* the pointer already points to) you will need to pass a pointer to a pointer and dereference it once to perform the assignment, i.e.,

```
int ModifyPointer( int **v )
{
    // error checking and whatnot
    *v = realloc(*v,n*sizeof(int));
}
```

Think of it this way; you have a pointer `p` that resides at memory address 0xA and points to memory address 0xFF.  You pass `p` to a function and a copy `v` is created.  The copy `v` resides at memory address 0x2A, but still points to memory address 0xFF.

```
                     p(0xA)      v(0x2A)
                       |            |
                        \          /
                         \        /
                          \      /
                            0xFF
```

So, when you dereference either pointer you end up referring to the same chunk of memory, *but the pointers themselves live in different places in memory*.  Thus, when you modify the value of the copy it is not reflected in the original (i.e., realloc is creating a new pointer in a new memory location and assigning it to the variable `v`, but `p` remains unchanged.)

Comment: I have seen pointers, pointer pointers and even pointer pointer pointers but this answer is just awesome. :)

Comment: `realloc(v,...` -> `realloc(*v,...` ... and in C, the cast is unnecessary.

Comment: @Jim Balter: Thanks, I just copied that in without thinking.  Fixed.