# How do I handle a struct component which points to an array whose size won't be known until after the struct is declared?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I have a struct with a pointer component. The pointer will point to an array whose size will be determined after the struct is declared. I will need to malloc memory and then assign it to the pointer. Somehow passing this pointer through function calls causes problems. Here is a simple example which recreates my error:

```
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct mystruct mystruct;
struct mystruct{
int dim;
double *dubarr;
double dub;
};

int getarr(int *dim, double *dubarr){
*dim = 2; /* The value of dim is not known until this function is called */
dubarr = malloc(*dim * sizeof(double));
double test;
int i;
for(i=0;i<*dim;i++)
  {
  dubarr[i] = (i+1)*7.0;
  test = dubarr[i];
  printf("dubarr[%i] = %.15e\n", i, test);
  }
return 1;}

int initmystruct(mystruct *data){
getarr(&(data->dim),data->dubarr);
data->dub = (data->dim)*((data->dubarr)[0]);
return 1;}

int main(void){

mystruct data;
initmystruct(&data);
double test;
int i;
for(i=0;i<data.dim;i++)
  {
  test = (data.dubarr)[i];
  printf("dubarr[%i] = %.15e\n", i, test);
  }

/* I would do "free(data.dubarr);" here but it causes a crash */

return 1;}
```

The code compiles with no warnings but the components of `data.dubarr` do not maintain their values through the function calls. Here is the output:

```
dubarr[0] = 7.000000000000000e+00
dubarr[1] = 1.400000000000000e+01
dubarr[0] = 2.002400628035951e+176
dubarr[1] = 2.186218092030684e-154
```

Please point out all my mistakes :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C program, pointer argument won't hold values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240193/c-program-pointer-argument-wont-hold-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C uses pass by value. So here:

```
int getarr(int *dim, double *dubarr)
```

the function receives `dubarr`, a pointer to `double`, passed by value. So, whatever the function assigns to `dubarr` cannot be seen outside `getarr`. Note that the implementation of `getarr` modifies `dubarr`, but the caller will not see those modifications.

Contrast that with how you handle `dim`, where you modify `*dim`. Similarly look at the call to `getarr` in your code:

```
getarr(&(data->dim), data->dubarr);
```

Observe how the two arguments are treated differently. For the first argument you pass the address of a variable, for the second you pass the value of the pointer.

Instead you need:

```
int getarr(int *dim, double **dubarr)
```

And then assign to `*dubarr` like this:

```
*dubarr = malloc(...);
```

And call `getarr` like this:

```
getarr(&(data->dim), &(data->dubarr));
```

Comment: Impressive. Very nice.